# VBA Counting until value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I need to count the values down from cell A:2 until the value changes(The sheet from which I will be counting will have repeating values for an unknown amount of cells, followed by another set of values), however the initial value will never be the same. This is the code that I currently have, which counts until there is no data in the cell. Any help would be appreciated.

```
            SourceRange = 1
            Do Until Cells(SourceRange, 1) = ""
                SourceRange = SourceRange + 1
```

Comment: `Do Until Cells(SourceRange, 1) <> Cells(SourceRange+1, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    v = Range("A2").Value
    For i = 3 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> v Then
            MsgBox CStr(i - 2)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub CountSame()

    Dim OC As Range, CC As Range

    Set OC = Range("a2")
    Set CC = OC

    Do Until CC.Value <> OC.Value
       Set CC = CC.Offset(1, 0)
       a = a + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox a

End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Function CountConsecutiveSame(rng as Range) as Long
    With Rng
        Set found = Range(.Offset(1), .End(xlDown)).Find(What:=.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then CountConsecutiveSame = found.Row - .Row + 1
    End With
End Function
```

To be used like

```
MsgBox CountConsecutiveSame(Range("A2"))
```